# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error when trying to build app with Admob

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I just integrated google admob into my iOS app. When I compile I'm getting the following errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CACurrentMediaTime", referenced from:
      l858 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
  "_CVBufferGetAttachment", referenced from:
      l2558 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
  "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate", referenced from:
      l2560 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
  "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage", referenced from:
      l2561 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
  "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush", referenced from:
      l2559 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
  "_CVOpenGLESTextureGetName", referenced from:
      l2561 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
```

There are more errors like that as well. I installed admob separately from firebase as I didn't want to use firebase, just admob. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, you can always Google the undefined symbol its referring to to find out which framework you are missing. In this case Google [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://www.google.com/search?q=CACurrentMediaTime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which is referenced from [`QuartzCore`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore). So, to fix your issue you need to `import QuartzCore`.

Comment: I followed this to fix it. I posted another answer that shows the frameworks I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the framework "CoreGraphics" to your project and it will be ok.

Comment: I don't see core animation is the list of frameworks to link to. I'm on Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

Add all framework to project which are comes with Admob framework.

Comment: Forgot to add that I did add all the frameworks that admob asked for in their getting started tutorial.

Comment: No. I had to add more frameworks then they listed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the answer from this link:

[GoogleMobileAds iOS 9 link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942524/googlemobileads-ios-9-link-error)

Admob has additional frameworks that they don't mention in their tutorial.The picture from the link above is posted below.

I'm not marking this as the answer because technically Daniel Storm's answer is what lead me to find this stackoverflow link. By googling the symbol you can find the framework it is a part of to solve any of these kind of errors.

[image]